# Nyquist rate of a function convolved with itself

Tags: fourier-transform

From Schaum's Outline, Digital Signal Processing, Second Edition, 2012, page 155:

If the Nyquist rate for x(t) is:

$$\Omega_s$$

what is the Nyquist rate for:

$$ y(t) = x^{2}(t)$$

**Solution:**

$$y(t)= x(t)x(t)$$

Multiplication in time domain equals convulsion in frequency domain.  Therefore:

$$Y(j\Omega) = \frac{1}{2\pi}X(j\Omega) * X(j\Omega)$$

Then the book say because of this relationship the highest frequency in y(t) will be twice the frequency of x(t).

My question is:

**How can you make this inference from the convulution of X with itself in the frequency domain?**

A few definitions:

$$ F(j\Omega) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)e^{-j\Omega t} dt$$

Comment: see my answer below. Does it answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

In the convolution integral
$$ Y(j \Omega)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}X(j\Omega') X(j(\Omega-\Omega')) \,d\Omega',$$
both arguments are nonzero and there is a nonzero contribution to the integral when $\Omega\in (2\Omega_0-\epsilon,\Omega_0]$$\Omega'\in (\Omega_0-\epsilon,\Omega_0],$ where $\Omega_0$ is the Nyquist frequency of $X(j\Omega).$